# What do the various interfaces provided by cnosdb do, and what are the differences between them?

Tags: cnosdb

```
CnosDB meta Network port:

TCP 8901 : The communication port used for inter-Meta services, but also responsible for receiving requests from cnosdb.
CnosDB Network port:

TCP 8902 : indicates the http listening port for receiving requests from the client.
TCP 8903 : Grpc listening port, used to receive GRPC requests from clients.
TCP 8904 : Listening port of the Flight RPC, used to receive client requests of the Flight SQL protocol.
TCP 8905 : Indicates the TCP listening port of CnosDB, which is used to receive TCP client requests.
```

According to the official documentation, it seems that every interface is useful. When I expose the interfaces to the outside world in k8s, I will choose to expose 4 to the client at once. But it always feels like there are too many. Can http, grpc, and tcp be combined?